# Selection option in Alert Box (Titanium Appcelerator)

Tags: titanium-mobile

How to add select options in Aler Dialog as shown below using Titanium Appcelerator?
I checked the documentation [in this link](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.AlertDialog), but there is no much reference.

is it possible in Titanium?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i think at present titanium does have the feature you shown in image....

but we can create view which looks like alert view and show....

those button shown in link are general alerts

[image]